# Ruby on rails Common error: Params missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I am building a Order management system. I recently posted a problem about adding a order to a customer. It seems that i have fixed it for 99%. if i look in my terminal it first finds the current customer ID and then creates a new order. The following result is.

`Customer Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE "customers"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 111]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "orders" ("customer_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["customer_id", 111], ["created_at", "2015-11-12 13:28:21.185604"], ["updated_at", "2015-11-12 13:28:21.185604"]]
   (8.2ms)  commit transaction`

But the problem is, it doesn't add the params. I did this intentionally just to check if my syntax would execute the following sql statement. But once i add params i get a common error "param is missing or the value is empty: order"

Here is my code:

#### Controller

```
def createorders
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id]) #find current id??
  #current_user = Order.find(params[:id])
  @orders = @customer.orders.new(order_params)

  if @orders.save
    flash[:notice] = "Subject created successfully"
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  else
    #If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
    render('new') #het zit in de new.html template
  end
end

private 

  def order_params
    #same as using "params[:subject]", expect that it:
    # - raises an error if :subject is not present
    # - allows listed attributes to be mass-assigned
    params.require(:order).permit(:pakket, :verstuurt)
  end
end
```

#### View

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'index'}, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="subject new">
    <h2>Create Subject</h2>

    <%= form_for(:order, :url=> {:action => 'createorders'}) do |f| %>
    <table summary="subject form fields">
        <tr>
            <th>pakket</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:pakket) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>verstuurt</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:verstuurt) %></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <div class="form-buttons">
        <%= submit_tag("Create Subject") %>
    </div>

    <% end %>
</div>
```

#### Error message

> ActionController::ParameterMissing in OrderController#createorders
>   param is missing or the value is empty: order
>
> ```
> Extracted source (around line #107):
> 105
> 106
> 107
> 108
> 109
> 110
>
>
>   def order_params
>   params.require(:order).permit(:pakket, :verstuurt)
>       end
> end
> ```

#### Serverside Log

> Started GET "/order/createorders?id=111" for ::1 at 2015-11-13
>   11:58:30 +0100 Processing by OrderController#createorders as HTML
>   Parameters: {"id"=>"111"}   Customer Load (0.2ms)  SELECT 
>   "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE "customers"."id" = ? LIMIT 1 
>   [["id", 111]] Completed 400 Bad Request in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
>
> ```
> ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: order):   app/controllers/order_controller.rb:107:in
> ```
>
> `order_params'   app/controllers/order_controller.rb:44:in`
>   createorders'
>
> ```
>   Rendered /Users/cecil/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb
> ```
>
> (8.3ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/cecil/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.6ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/cecil/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
>   (1.3ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/cecil/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb
>   within rescues/layout (68.2ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/cecil/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb
>   (0.4ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/cecil/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb
>   within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/cecil/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb
>   within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/cecil/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb
>   within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/cecil/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb
>   within layouts/javascript (60.3ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/cecil/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb
>   within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/cecil/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.5ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/cecil/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb
>   (124.2ms)

Thank you stackoverflow for showing me support. I am new with ruby, and i understand i am making noob mistakes. So pointing out flaws are welcome!

Comment: Where is your `order_params` method defined?

Comment: Yeah, you are showing `customer_params` but you are calling `order_params`. Where is `order_params`?

Comment: @sunnK,  i pasted the wrong param. I pasted the correct one now

Comment: can you add the logs showing what params are being sent to `createorders` action?

Comment: @basia Yes! done it.

Comment: @Jason First it shows a list of customers, and then when you press on the button"show" it displays the customer.id. And in my "show page" i have a button called "add order". And that is what you see above.

Comment: You should post your full error readout.

Comment: How about everything that the server log shows when your browser makes a request that leads to the error?

Comment: @jason Done that as well

Answer (score 0):

I was ignoring your minor, non-fatal issues earlier while I was focused on locating the major issue, but I'll include them now that the major issue is apparent.

First, I'll discuss Rails naming conventions a little bit. You have two models, which are named `Customer` and `Order`. You've used the singular form of the noun for these, which is good. Each instance of a model is one thing, so it should be singular. Your controller for the `Order` model actions, however, should be named with the plural form, so it should be called `OrdersController`. This is because it controls the actions related to all of your orders. This leads us to your `createorders` action, which would make a little more sense if it were named `createorder`, since it only creates one `Order`. Actually, though, the convention is to name that action `create`. The action is in your `OrdersController`, so we already assume that it deals with an `Order` instance. (When you have Rails automatically generate REST-ful routes for a model's controller with the `resources` function, it assumes you have an action named `create`.) Lastly, in your `create` method, the new `Order` instance that will be referenced in your view should be called `@order` instead of `@orders`, since it contains only one `Order`.

Now things get a little more complicated. Your `param is missing` error means exactly that. The parameters for the new `Order` instance are missing. The request to the server that is producing that error is a `GET` request that has only one parameter, which you're providing in your URL with `?id=111`. Your form's data is not being submitted to the server with that `GET` request. You should be doing a `POST` request to create a new `Order`. I'm going to avoid further exploration (and speculation without seeing your full code) regarding why things aren't working right now and I'll just suggest some key adjustments. It's turning in to a bit a puzzle to figure out how your app works without seeing all of the pieces.

In **routes.rb**, you should have this line:

```
resources :customers, :orders
```

I've made minimal changes to the view you provided, which I assume is called **show.html.erb** and is in your **app/views/customers** folder:

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'index'}, :class => 'back-link') %>
<div class="subject new">
    <h2>Create Subject</h2>
    <%= form_for @order do |f| %>
    <table summary="subject form fields">
        <tr>
            <th>pakket</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:pakket) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>verstuurt</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:verstuurt) %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <%= f.hidden_field :customer_id %>
    <div class="form-buttons">
        <%= submit_tag("Create Subject") %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is the necessary code from **customers_controller.rb** to support it:

```
def show
    customer = Customer.find params[:id]
    @order = customer.orders.new
end
```

Notice, in the view, the parameter for `form_for` is the instance that was created in the controller. Also, I've added a hidden field to submit the `customer_id` with the new `Order` data.

Finally, your `create` action in **orders_controller.rb** might look like this:

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)
  if @order.save
    flash[:notice] = "Subject created successfully"
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  else
    render 'customers/show'
  end
end
```

And your `order_params` method should be changed to include the `customer_id` parameter:

```
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:pakket, :verstuurt, :customer_id)
end
```

Notice that on a failed `save`, the action renders `customers/show`, because this is the page that they were on where the save failed. This will allow Rails to re-populate the form (in the same context) with the data that was present during the failed submission.

Comment: Thank you, i took note on your advice. And i have edited the code. Unfortunately the same error. And i do understand that if you had seen my full code you would understand it better. I have a confession to make. I have to create instances, first create action is for customer, and the second is for order. first one is named "create" and the second is name "createorders". This makes it of course messy but if i put them together then i cant create Customers. It wont even allow me to go to the show field. Then i understand why the parameters are empty. But thank you for the advice and time

Comment: Your 'create` action in **customers_controller.rb** should create a `Customer` and your `create` action in **orders_controller.rb** should create an `Order`. When you start to improvise like you're doing, problems quickly accumulate and you wind up with `GET` requests happening with your forms. Here's my advice: Create a new app, open up a text editor next to a window with your old code in it, and write the app the way Rails was intended to be used. Use your existing code for reference, but make sure you force yourself to follow Rails convention. You're developing terrible habits right now.